# what is the role of the FacebookMiddleware in External Login?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Core Identity in my application in which I enable External Login (to Facebook); and my question is what is the role of the FacebookMiddleware after the user clicks the Facebook button in the Log In page, redirected to Facebook Log In page, clicks OK, and then redirected back by Facebook, to the ExternalLoginCallback method... where is FacebookMiddleware in all this scheme and what it does ?

Answer (score 0):

As the name says, FacebookMiddleware is the component which is authenticating users using Facebook.

When you call the UseFacebookAuthentication call,it basically wires up the FacebookMiddleware.

FacebookMiddleware internally uses FacebookHandler

Nothing explains better than the code itself,so here's the code of FacebookHandler

```cs
 internal class FacebookHandler : OAuthHandler<FacebookOptions>
        {
            public FacebookHandler(HttpClient httpClient) : base(httpClient)
            {
            }

            protected override async Task<AuthenticationTicket>   CreateTicketAsync(ClaimsIdentity identity, AuthenticationProperties properties, OAuthTokenResponse tokens)
            {
                string text = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(this.get_Options().get_UserInformationEndpoint(), "access_token", tokens.get_AccessToken());
                if (this.get_Options().SendAppSecretProof)
                {
                    text = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(text, "appsecret_proof", this.GenerateAppSecretProof(tokens.get_AccessToken()));
                }
                if (this.get_Options().Fields.get_Count() > 0)
                {
                    text = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(text, "fields", string.Join(",", this.get_Options().Fields));
                }
                HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await this.get_Backchannel().GetAsync(text, this.get_Context().get_RequestAborted());
                if (!httpResponseMessage.get_IsSuccessStatusCode())
                {
                    throw new HttpRequestException(string.Format("Failed to retrieve Facebook user information ({0}) Please check if the authentication information is correct and the corresponding Facebook Graph API is enabled.", httpResponseMessage.get_StatusCode()));
                }
                JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(await httpResponseMessage.get_Content().ReadAsStringAsync());
                AuthenticationTicket authenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), properties, this.get_Options().get_AuthenticationScheme());
                OAuthCreatingTicketContext oAuthCreatingTicketContext = new OAuthCreatingTicketContext(authenticationTicket, this.get_Context(), this.get_Options(), this.get_Backchannel(), tokens, jObject);
                string id = FacebookHelper.GetId(jObject);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
                {
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", id, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string", this.get_Options().get_ClaimsIssuer()));
                }
                string ageRangeMin = FacebookHelper.GetAgeRangeMin(jObject);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ageRangeMin))
                {
                    identity.AddClaim(new  Claim("urn:facebook:age_range_min", ageRangeMin, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string", this.get_Options().get_ClaimsIssuer()));
                }
                string ageRangeMax = FacebookHelper.GetAgeRangeMax(jObject);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ageRangeMax))
                {
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:facebook:age_range_max", ageRangeMax, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string", this.get_Options().get_ClaimsIssuer()));
                }
                string birthday = FacebookHelper.GetBirthday(jObject);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(birthday))
                {
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/dateofbirth", birthday, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string", this.get_Options().get_ClaimsIssuer()));
                }
                string email = FacebookHelper.GetEmail(jObject);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress", email, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string", this.get_Options().get_ClaimsIssuer()));
            }
            string firstName = FacebookHelper.GetFirstName(jObject);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName))
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname", firstName, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string", this.get_Options().get_ClaimsIssuer()));
            }
            string gender = FacebookHelper.GetGender(jObject);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(gender))
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/gender", gender, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string", this.get_Options().get_ClaimsIssuer()));
            }
            string lastName = FacebookHelper.GetLastName(jObject);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname", lastName, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string", this.get_Options().get_ClaimsIssuer()));
            }
            string link = FacebookHelper.GetLink(jObject);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(link))
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:facebook:link", link, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string", this.get_Options().get_ClaimsIssuer()));
            }
            string location = FacebookHelper.GetLocation(jObject);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:facebook:location", location, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string", this.get_Options().get_ClaimsIssuer()));
            }
            string locale = FacebookHelper.GetLocale(jObject);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(locale))
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/locality", locale, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string", this.get_Options().get_ClaimsIssuer()));
            }
            string middleName = FacebookHelper.GetMiddleName(jObject);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(middleName))
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:facebook:middle_name", middleName, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string", this.get_Options().get_ClaimsIssuer()));
            }
            string name = FacebookHelper.GetName(jObject);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", name, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string", this.get_Options().get_ClaimsIssuer()));
            }
            string timeZone = FacebookHelper.GetTimeZone(jObject);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(timeZone))
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:facebook:timezone", timeZone, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string", this.get_Options().get_ClaimsIssuer()));
            }
            await this.get_Options().get_Events().CreatingTicket(oAuthCreatingTicketContext);
            return oAuthCreatingTicketContext.get_Ticket();
        }

        private string GenerateAppSecretProof(string accessToken)
        {
            string result;
            using (HMACSHA256 hMACSHA = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.get_ASCII().GetBytes(base.get_Options().AppSecret)))
            {
                byte[] array = hMACSHA.ComputeHash(Encoding.get_ASCII().GetBytes(accessToken));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    stringBuilder.Append(array[i].ToString("x2", CultureInfo.get_InvariantCulture()));
                }
                result = stringBuilder.ToString();
            }
            return result;
        }

        protected override string FormatScope()
        {
            return string.Join(",", base.get_Options().get_Scope());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone runs into the same problem: the error is thrown from this piece of code from the middleware:

`var response = Backchannel.GetAsync(endpoint).Result;
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new HttpRequestException($"Failed to retrieve Facebook user information ({response.StatusCode}) Please check if the authentication information is correct and the corresponding Facebook Graph API is enabled.");
            }`

In short, the developer decided that if status code is not a successful one, just throw a generic error message. In other to know that the real error is, you can use tools such as Fiddler to capture responses from Facebook which in my case looks like the below:

> {"error":{"message":"Syntax error \"Expected end of string instead of \";\".\" at character 5: email;first_name;last_name","type":"OAuthException","code":2500,"fbtrace_id":"xxxxxxxx"}}